# Available yeoman generator for Angular 2

Tags: angular, yeoman-generator

There is the official Angular generator, and many users provided ones for Angular 1. But I haven't found a generator for Angular 2.

Does such a yeoman generator exist already?

Comment: I don't know about generators, but there are plenty of helpful seeds.  One such: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed or https://github.com/gdi2290/angular2-webpack-seed

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Please add it as an answer. It's the best information I got on this question, so I'd like to reward you with 'Accepted Answer':-)

Comment: Looks like someone found what you are really looking for :).

Comment: Did you run into any issues ? what's your feedback ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

### The Official tool for scaffolding Angular2 project is  Angular-Cli https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

There are few generators for Angular2

Please try them and post some feedback or issues in the github

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular2
   (https://github.com/swirlycheetah/generator-angular2)
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-gulp-angular2 (https://github.com/x6doooo/generator-gulp-angular2)
3. https://github.com/joshuacaron/generator-angular2-gulp-webpack
4. https://www.npmjs.com/package/slush-angular2
   (https://github.com/TheVelourFog/slush-angular2)
5. https://github.com/cureon/angular2-sass-gulp-boilerplate

Generator for creating Angular2 library or plugin

1. https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library

Angular2 Fullstack generator

1. https://github.com/ericmdantas/generator-ng-fullstack

Ionic2 generator (Gulp; comes in ES6 and TS varieties)

1. http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/

Comment: It looks like the `slush-angular2` is not a yeoman generator, but a slush generator.

Comment: Isn't this better moved to a tag wiki? Or made community wiki, given the new answer?

Comment: And if you are gonna do a Java backend then dont forget https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster PS: I'm a core contributor

Comment: Angular-CLI may be the "official" generator, but it can be quite buggy.  Also, the team makes no secret that it is still in beta and that there will be breaking changes, apparently without much concern about people who are using it.  I've had to rollback numerous projects to earlier versions simply because "latest" has broken something.  Caveat Emptor...

Answer (score 44):

Here's what I've gathered so far:

## Angular 2 scaffolding

### Yeoman generators

#### [generator-angular2](https://github.com/swirlycheetah/generator-angular2)

Outdated and very rustic. No preprocessors.

#### [generator-gulp-angular2](https://github.com/x6doooo/generator-gulp-angular2)

Outdated. Out-of-the-box `build.dev` fails. Features SASS and Jade.

#### [generator-angular2-gulp-webpack](https://github.com/joshuacaron/generator-angular2-gulp-webpack)

No preprocessors.

### Other options

#### [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) (Official generator)

Based on [ember-cli](http://ember-cli.com), still on alpha stage.
No preprocessors. Also, I don't see a way to add preprocessing, except by creating Ember add-ons:
http://www.emberaddons.com/.

#### [Angular 2 Seed](http://mgechev.github.io/angular2-seed/)

Standalone scaffolding. Features Gulp and Webpack. Has instructions on how to install preprocessors. Needs manual Gulp configuration when
adding dependencies.
All code is written in Typescript.

#### [Angular 2 Seed (ng2-material)](https://github.com/justindujardin/angular2-seed)

A fork of **angular2-seed** incorporating [Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) ([ng2-material](https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material)).

#### [Angular 2 Seed - Jade](https://github.com/LuxDie/angular2-seed-jade)

A fork of **angular2-seed** incorporating Bootstrap and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) preprocessors (by yours truly).

#### [Angular 2 Starter](https://angularclass.github.io/angular2-webpack-starter/)

An Angular 2 Starter kit featuring Angular 2 (Router, Http, Forms, Services, Tests, E2E), Karma, Protractor, Jasmine, TypeScript, and
Webpack by @AngularClass.

#### [angular2-sass-gulp-boilerplate](https://github.com/cureon/angular2-sass-gulp-boilerplate)

Although it's titled "yeoman generator" it just seems to be standalone scaffolding.

#### [slush-angular2](https://github.com/thevelourfog/slush-angular2)

Generator for [Slush](http://slushjs.github.io).

Comment: So which would you recommend as of right now @LuxDie ? I was told by someone with more experience to use Generator Angular2 but... I don't see much improvement tbh, I thought it was me since I don't have any experience with gulp

Comment: I'm sorry @monkeyintern but I no longer keep updated about this topic.

Answer (score 4):

[generator-ng2-webpack](https://github.com/cmelion/generator-ng2-webpack)
is kept relatively up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Basic bash to create angular2 app. As instructed in official website.
[angular2-app-generator](https://github.com/deepakshrma/angular2-app-generator)
Kindly check this out.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Angular2 Application Scaffolder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular2-application-scaffolder). It comes with Gulp, Sass, TypeScript, Karma, Jasmine, Bootstrap... Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The yeoman official tutorial is using [generator-fountain-webapp](https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-webapp), which supports angular2. It's in v1.0.0 rc at the moment but quite uptodate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest these for Angular 2 with MEAN Yeoman Generator:

https://github.com/jussikinnula/angular2-mean-starter

https://github.com/giacomocerquone/angular2-mean-starter

Answer (score 0):

This one looks pretty up-to-date and works: https://github.com/ngx-rocket/generator-ngx-rocket

Still trying them...