# Best yeoman generator for angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, yeoman-generator

Which yeoman generator is best for creating web application using Angular2 + Typescript?

Comment: Not yeoman but you can take a look at angular-cli

Comment: But i need proper scaffolding of an app with Angular2 + Typescript which yeoman generator provides.

Comment: angular-cli creates a new project with angular2 and typescript and some generator commands

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Available yeoman generator for angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649578/available-yeoman-generator-for-angular-2)